# Multiple Statements For The Ternary Operator Of PHP

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I'm wondering if I could use the ternary operator for something like this:

```
var string = "";
if (something) {
  string = "foo"
} else if (somethingElse) {
  string = "bar";
} else if (bla) {
  string = "pool";
} else if (xxxxx) {
  string = "coffee";
} else {
  string = "";
}
```

As far as I remember, I can do this in Java language:

```
String string = something?"foo":somethingElse?"bar":bla?"pool":xxxxx?"coffee":"";
```

But I'm not sure about PHP, I'm not even sure if it's OK to use ternary operator in this case or not.

Comment: You can, but don't! A series of if/elseif/else statements is a lot more readable and understandable that nested ternary operators.... and debugging becomes an exercise in pain-management. The PHP docs warn about nested ternaries being counter-intuitive for a reason

Comment: Or may be a `switch-case`.

Comment: @b0s3 Yeah guess I'll stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

E.g

```
 if (something) {
      string = "foo"
    } else if (somethingElse) {
      string = "bar";
    } else if (bla) {
      string = "pool";
    } else if (xxxxx) {
      string = "coffee";
    } else {
      string = "";
}
```

is equivalent to in PHP

```
(something) ? 'foo' : ((somethingElse) ? 'bar' : ((bla) ? 'pool' : ((xxxxx) ? 'coffe' : '')));
```

Comment: Thanks, but those brackets drove me crazy, can you explain what's happening?